# Rails nested form and bootstrap tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, nested-forms

I have a nested model (`exptype`), and I'm using bootstrap tabs to show the `has_many` relationship between the parent (`experiment`) and it's children (`exptype`).

So far my code looks like:

```
 <div role="tabpanel">
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <% @experiment.exptypes.each do |e| %>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#exptype<%=e.id%>" aria-controls="exptype<%=e.id%>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><%=e.get_name%></a></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>

      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <%= f.fields_for :exptypes do |builder| %>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="exptype<%=builder.object.id%>">
            <%=builder.object.id%>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The tabs themselves work. But the `tab-content` does not. What happens is for each tab, all the `builder.object.id`'s are shown in **each** tab, and not in their respective ones.

I believe it's the `fields_for` loop that is causing the problem. However, I want to be able to have a tab that allows for the addition of a new `exptype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <% @experiment.exptypes.each do |e| %>    
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="exptype<%=builder.object.id%>">
      <%= f.fields_for :exptypes, e do |builder| %>        
        <%=builder.object.id%>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

`fields_for` is not a loop and will only create one div. Note that i also added `e` to the `fields_for` call. Take a look at here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: Added the code, changes can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/lutrasdebtra/98533eb7a907e71f4aff). However, the behaviour is still the same.

Comment: I updated the code. I guess the `div` should be outside of the loop.

Comment: I tried that just before you updated your answer. Same problem!

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle from the generated HTML or post here?

Comment: [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/bkhcjh7j/) the jsfiddle of the generated html relevant to the tabs. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ex1ouzbm/1/) is the entire page dump.

Comment: Try with `fields_for` call inside of the div. I updated the code.

Comment: It should be `id="exptype<%=e.id%>"`, but otherwise that worked! Thanks.